# modalpopupextender not recognising the BackgroundCssClass when using .show()

Tags: c#, asp.net, modalpopupextender

I am having a problem getting a modalpopupextender to display when using the .show() in code behind.

When using the link button the modal popup works exactly as expected, however when i invoke it from the code behind, the popup is not modal and I can enter data into text box's, click other buttons etc. Note the linkbutton will usually be hidden 
with style="display:none;".

I am trying to setup the popup to display a message depending upon which button is clicked.

I have copied the code below (removed the extra tables detail to save space).

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="FrmTransaction.aspx.cs" Inherits="Cloud9.FrmTransaction" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" />

    <div runat="server" id="PageDetailDiv" class="pagedetail">
        <asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" />

        <asp:Table runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="80%">
            <asp:TableRow runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMsg" CssClass="Msg" EnableViewState="false" />
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow ID="trSearch" runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                    <div align="left">
                        <asp:Label CssClass="formCapture" Text='Field' runat="server" ID="lblSearchField" AssociatedControlID="tbSearchField" />
                        <obout:OboutTextBox FolderStyle="Styles/Obout/TextBox" runat="server" ID="tbSearchField" Width="300px" />
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label CssClass="formCapture" Text='Lookup' runat="server" ID="lblSearch" AssociatedControlID="tbSearch" />
                        <obout:OboutTextBox FolderStyle="Styles/Obout/TextBox" runat="server" ID="tbSearch" Width="300px" />
                        <asp:Button ID="SearchButton" runat="server" Text="Find" CommandName="Search" CausesValidation="False"
                            OnCommand="btnClick_Search" CssClass="btnDefault" onMouseOver="this.CssClassName='btnDefaultHover'" onMouseOut="this.CssClassName='btnDefault'" />
                    </div>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>

        <asp:Table runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="80%">
            <asp:TableRow ID="trButton" runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <div align="center">
                        <asp:Button id="btnInsert" runat="server" Text="Insert" CommandName="Insert" CausesValidation="True" OnCommand="btnClick_Insert"
                            CssClass="btnDefault" onMouseOver="this.CssClassName='btnDefaultHover'" onMouseOut="this.CssClassName='btnDefault'"/>
                        &nbsp; 
                        <asp:Button id="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" CausesValidation="True" OnCommand="btnClick_Update"
                            CssClass="btnDefault" onMouseOver="this.CssClassName='btnDefaultHover'" onMouseOut="this.CssClassName='btnDefault'"/>
                        &nbsp; 
                        <asp:Button id="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" CausesValidation="False" OnCommand="btnClick_Delete"
                            CssClass="btnDefault" onMouseOver="this.CssClassName='btnDefaultHover'" onMouseOut="this.CssClassName='btnDefault'"/>
                        &nbsp; 
                        <asp:Button id="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" CausesValidation="False" OnCommand="btnClick_Cancel" 
                            CssClass="btnDefault" onMouseOver="this.CssClassName='btnDefaultHover'" onMouseOut="this.CssClassName='btnDefault'"/>
                    </div>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>

        <asp:Panel CssClass="modalPopup" runat="server" ID="pnlMessage" >
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID = "lblMessg" />
            <br />
            <asp:Button id="btnOKMessage" Text="OK!" Runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" CausesValidation="false" OnCommand="btnClick_Cancel"
                class="btnPgeSmall" onMouseOver="this.className='btnPgeSmallHover'" onMouseOut="this.className='btnPgeSmall'" />
        </asp:Panel>

        <asp:LinkButton ID="UsedByModal" Text="here" runat="server" />
        <ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlMessage" TargetControlID="UsedByModal"
            BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" CancelControlID="btnOKMessage" OkControlID="btnOKMessage" />
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

the relevant part of the CSS .....

```
.modalBackground {
    background-color:Gray;
    filter:alpha(opacityp);
    opacity:0.7;
}

.modalPopup {
    background-color:#F6F6EA;
    border-width:3px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#c0c0c0;
    padding:3px;
    width:50%;
}
```

I have been looking for an answer for the last 3 days and am now totally stuck. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found IT!

To find the problem I rewrote the page removing all the controls and started from a simple page with 1xTextbox and 1xButton and the asp:Modalpopupextender, and made sure it was all working as expected. I then started adding controls / functionality to the page testing along the way. Long story short the problem was the asp:ValidationSummary.

I then re-instated the page (as displayed above) without the ValidationSummary control it all worked beautifully.

I am yet to understand why this fixed the problem, but the page and the popup work.

If anyone has an explanation I would appreciate it!

Thanks

Comment: I know you found a solution but I noticed a typo in this line of your css: "filter:alpha(opacityp)"  - is the "p" intentional?

Answer (score 0):

This class is producing right results for me, You can modify it to suit your needs.

```
.modalBackground
{
    background-color: #000000;
    opacity: .15;
    filter: alpha(opacity=15);
    -moz-opacity: .15;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I tried replacing my class with yours and received the same result. The problem is that for some reason the page is not recognizing the class at all when i use any other control other than the link button. By not recognizing the modalBackground class its not formatting the popup as modal.

Comment: try this ModalPopupExtender1.BackgroundCssClass = "modalBackground";  before show in code-behind.